# Is it possible to modify/append to the output text of an existing Python Logger object?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using a Python module with a Logger object that outputs logs as so:

```
INFO:ProgressLogger:Started work. Items to process: 1.
INFO:ProgressLogger:1 items processed. Progress is 100%.
```

Is there any way to modify the output text of the `ProgressLogger` object so that it also appends custom text like:

```
INFO:ProgressLogger:Started work. Items to process: 1. {insert customer text here}
INFO:ProgressLogger:1 items processed. Progress is 100%. {insert customer text here}
```

I know I can edit the code in the module for the `ProgressLogger` class so that it can take in custom text values but wondering if there is a simpler way to just append text to an existing Logger object's output?

Answer (score 0):

`Logger`s don't output information, `Handler`s do. The output that you showed is controlled by a `Formatter`, so you may be able do what you need with a custom `Formatter` subclass. You haven't given enough information to provide any more detail and to determine whether or not it's feasible to do *exactly* what you want, but almost certainly the custom `Formatter` would be the way to approach it.